# Why I can't access to the "seconds" propery of this object? How can I convert it into a Date?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular project and I am going crazy trying to extract a date from an object.

I will try to explain you my exact problem:

In my code I have something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeService.currentMessage.subscribe(employee => {
                                                      console.log("EMPLOYEE: ", employee);
                                                      

                                                      this.employeeDetailsSelected = employee;

                                                      console.log("DATE 1: ", this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate);
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
    .................................................................
}
```

So here I am printing the value of the **birthDate** field of my **employeeDetailsSelected** object.

This print out the following value:

```
DATE 1:  
t {seconds: 103244400, nanoseconds: 0}
nanoseconds: 0
seconds: 103244400
__proto__:
    C: ƒ (t)
    isEqual: ƒ (t)
    toDate: ƒ ()
    toJSON: ƒ ()
    toMillis: ƒ ()
    toString: ƒ ()
    valueOf: ƒ ()
    constructor: ƒ t(t, e)
    __proto__: Object
```

So is it an object containing **seconds** and **nanoseconds**? Is it a TimeStamp?

I have to convert it into a date object so I was trying first to access to the **seconds** field of this object. So I tried to do something like this:

```
console.log("SECONDS: ", this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate["seconds"]);
```

But doing in this way my application crash and I obtain these errors into my Chrome console:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (employee-details.component.ts:67)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
    at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:76)
```

I am obtaining this exact error after that I insert this second console.log after the previous one

```
console.log("SECONDS: ", this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate["seconds"]);
```

removing this line it works.

I was thinking that maybe I can use the **toDate()** method defined into the ****proto****. But how?

Comment: It's telling you `this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate` is undefined.

Comment: ok but at the line before I can print it...

Comment: Try calling toJSON() method on it in prior console line

Comment: Guys, I suggest you do NOT trust console.log especially with async code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to debugging with the `console.log`, especially while subscribing an Observable. It is not the appropriate way of doing it.

Remember: you are subscribing `this.employeeService.currentMessage` listening for changes on the values.

The exception is clear, in that moment you try to access the property `seconds` your object is `undefined`:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (employee-details.component.ts:67)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:76)
```

To solve it ensure first that the object is not `undefined`then you can access its properties without JS exceptions.

eg.

```
var dateValue= this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate ? this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate.toDate() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toDate() method defined on **proto** directly on your object, because it inherits it from **proto**. Try `this.employeeDetailsSelected.birthDate.toDate()`. Also make sure this line goes in same place where your previous one (which had no troubles accessing `birthDate`) was.